# Enable pagination on list intents Dialogflow

Tags: python, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have successfully retrieved all intents of Dialogflow by the following python code:

```
def list_intents(project_id):
    from google.cloud import dialogflow

    intents_client = dialogflow.IntentsClient()

    parent = dialogflow.AgentsClient.agent_path(project_id)

    intents = intents_client.list_intents(request={"parent": parent})

    for intent in intents:
        print("=" * 20)
        print("Intent name: {}".format(intent.name))
        print("Intent display_name: {}".format(intent.display_name))
        print("Action: {}\n".format(intent.action))
        print("Root followup intent: {}".format(intent.root_followup_intent_name))
        print("Parent followup intent: {}\n".format(intent.parent_followup_intent_name))

        print("Input contexts:")
        for input_context_name in intent.input_context_names:
            print("\tName: {}".format(input_context_name))

        print("Output contexts:")
        for output_context in intent.output_contexts:
            print("\tName: {}".format(output_context.name))
```

But when I run this code in production, then I can see that getting all intents causes some time. So I want to decide I will enable pagination on the list intents Dialogflow.

Ater researching I have got this link.

[Enable pagination on list_intents](https://github.com/googleapis/python-dialogflow/issues/166)

Here I have seen that page_size parameter was in google v2 Dialogflow. But this parameter is not present in the current Dialogflow API.

My objective is to get first 100 intents, then after clicking button I will get next 100 intents.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by 'this parameter is not present in the current Dialogflow API.'? According to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.ListIntentsResponse) by default page_size is set to 100.

Comment: Can I write intents = intents_client.list_intents(request={"parent": parent}, page_size= 100)? How can I get first 100 intents? Then after button pressing, I will call the API and get next 100 intents? Can I do this?

Comment: Can you try `intents_client.list_intents(request={"parent": parent,"page_size":100})`. Also Could you mention where are you trying to display/get the intents?

Comment: I am trying to display intents on the admin dashboard.

Comment: By admin dashboard are you refering to Dialogflow console? Also, according to this [doc](https://googleapis.dev/python/dialogflow/latest/_modules/google/cloud/dialogflow_v2/services/intents/async_client.html#IntentsAsyncClient.list_intents),pagination is automatically done when iterating over the response object.